# Eclipse 'Project Explorer' doesn't show all the files in the project

Tags: spring, eclipse, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I recently migrated from Win 7 to Win 10. I'm using Spring Tool Suite 3 ( Eclipse 2019-06 4.12.0). While on Win 7, I was working on gradle project and was able to view all the project file and build the project successfully. After migrating to Win 10 and importing the project into IDE, doesn't show all the files in the project. I'm able to build the project successfully and able to view all the files in 'Navigator' view as well but in 'Project explorer', some of the files are hidden. I also explored the menu (arrow) button in the project explorer and verified whether 'Filters and Customization' has any settings for hiding the file but there was no filters applied for hiding the files. How to rectify this issue so that I can view entire project structure instead of parking files.
Note - In 'Project Explorer', under particular project I'm able to view drow down arrows but not the actual content.[image: clipped project files]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was due to corrupted files in my workspace location i.e. .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core, and a exception was listed in 'Problems' view which said `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitDocumentProvider$AjcClosure3 cannot be found by org.eclipse.jdt`. **Fix** - I downloaded new STS and created new workspace (make sure inside this, there are no pre-existing .metadata folder) for my project and that fixed the issue.